# How to display the indicator bubble on top of the imageview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a string value (i.e.: numbers 1, 2, 3, ...) and I should display those on the top right corner of my ImageView.
How can I do that in android?
I have attached an image below in which I show arrows: I want something like that to display over my ImageView?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zPQt.png]

Please anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this : create `layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_widget"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
android:focusable="true" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="60dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logo"
    android:contentDescription="image"
    android:scaleType="center" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:background="@drawable/badge_count2"
    android:contentDescription="badge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And create `drawable\badge_count2.xml` for rectangle

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="@color/red" >
</solid>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" >
</stroke>

<padding
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:top="3dp" />

<corners android:radius="10dp" >
</corners>
```

And create `values\color.xml` and add:

```
 <color name="red">#e50822</color>
```

**OutPut:** [image]

**Update:** try to create `drawable\badge_count2.xml` for circle

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
android:useLevel="false" >
<solid android:color="@color/red" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

Comment: how to make that circle instead of rectangle is there any possibilities

Answer (score 2):

For ease and cover a lot of views you may use View badger library. This library provides different styles and animations for these badgers too.
You may find library and demo project [here](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger).

[image]